# Virtual Box cannot ping to my host machine (laptop)

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

can I ask some help. In my laptop I have virtual box with centOS ...I  set bridge Adapter in Virtual box settings...I also set static i.p address `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
DHCPCLASS=
HWADDR=08:00:27:84:08:78
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.10.66
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
```

In my host machine which is my laptop I also set static i.p

```
i.p address 192.168.10.65
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
```

My host mchine(laptop) can ping to virtual box(centos) 192.168.10.66
but my virtual box cannot ping to my laptop. Is there something missing ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out..its my host firewall...i can ping now.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you share some more details that might help others with a similar problem?  (Like how did you diagnose it and what did you do to fix it?)